# How can I use Turkish characters in Android EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, text-to-speech, turkish

In my text to speech (For Turkish) project, I have a EditText. User can enter Turkish chars (ı, ş, ç, ö), however editText converts them some other unknown chars. How can I prevent this?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of SDK you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have started to use Android 2.3.3 and Turkish Language is supported. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Check out this site. It explains all about the ability of implementing different languages in your app. It involves providing different string resources for each locale you want to support.

[Click here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Locale locale = new Locale("tr");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
```